# c++ recursive function with calling a class using a templatefunction

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I would like to have a function, that counts a value down to zero. in addition, i would like to call some code which class is passed as a template parameter.
but this code doesn't work. please can someone help me?
thanks a lot.

The error message is:

> "function template partial specialization 'foo<0, T>' is not allowed"

```
class Hello_World
{
    public:
        void hello(size_t number){
            cout << "hello " << number << endl;
        }
};


template<size_t SIZE, class T>
void foo()
{
    T t;
    t.hello(SIZE);
    foo<SIZE-1, Hello_World>();
}

template<class T>
void foo<0,T>()
{
    cout << "end." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo<4,Hello_World>();
}
```

Comment: What does not work, what have you tried so far,  is not compiling, crashing, ... ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] and the error message you get. This code wont compile for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't partially specialize template functions.  Wrap it in a class:

```
template <size_t SZ, typename T >
struct foo_impl
{
    static void call()
    {
        T().hello(SZ);
        foo_impl<SZ-1, T>::call();
    }
};

template < typename T >
struct foo_impl<0,T>
{
   // you get the idea...
};

template <size_t SZ, typename T >
void foo() { foo_impl<SZ,T>::call(); }
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, but this code doesn't work completely, i get the error message " 'call' is not a member of 'foo_impl<0u, Hello_World>' "  for line " foo_impl<SZ-1, T>::call(); "; i call it with " foo<3, Hello_World>(); "

Comment: @doktormoreau of course you have to implement that. Replace:  "// you get the idea" with an implementation of `call()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partially specialize a function template. However, you can partially specialize a functor (that basically acts like a function):

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t SIZE, class T>
struct foo {
    void operator()(){ foo<SIZE-1, T>()(); }
};

template<class T>
struct foo<0,T> {
    void operator()(){ std::cout << "end." <<std::endl; }
};

int main(){
    foo<3,int>()();
}
```